# Touch/Swipe UP/Down Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Vertical carousel which is responsive and working fine in any desktop but when i try to view it on a mobile/table there's no response when i swipe up/down it i tried to search about my problem and i ended up to ask question here

pls anyone can help me about may problem

heres the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dranir45/j7kpLb8s/18/) it automatically slide up and it can also control using mouse scroll. Now I want my Carousel to be responsive also in swipe up/down in mobile/table environment pls anyone can help me

this the my js for the scroll event

```js
$('#BNYCarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            $(this).carousel('next');
        }
        else{
            $(this).carousel('prev');
        }
    });
```